# Show a hidden div after an event is finished javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a code block

```
<div class="banner-area">
      <div class="banner-area__text">
        <span class="banner-area__green">Place</span>
        <span class="banner-area__red">Images</span>
      </div>
      <div class="map">
        <div
          id="container"
          ondrop="drop(event)"
          ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
          class="map1"
        ></div>
        <div
          id="container"
          ondrop="drop(event)"
          ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
          class="map2"
        ></div>
        <div
          id="container"
          ondrop="drop(event)"
          ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
          class="map3"
        ></div>
        <div
          id="container"
          ondrop="drop(event)"
          ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
          class="map4"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-area">
        <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img
            src="./img/hatirjheel.png"
            alt="hatirjheel"
            class="small-image"
            id="image1"
            draggable="true"
            ondragstart="drag(event)"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img
            src="./img/jamuna.png"
            alt="hatirjheel"
            class="small-image"
            id="image2"
            draggable="true"
            ondragstart="drag(event)"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img
            src="./img/padma.png"
            alt="hatirjheel"
            class="small-image"
            id="image3"
            draggable="true"
            ondragstart="drag(event)"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img
            src="./img/ruppur.png"
            alt="hatirjheel"
            class="small-image"
            id="image4"
            draggable="true"
            ondragstart="drag(event)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-area-2" id="div1">
      <div class="text-area">
        <div class="text-1 anime-text">
          <span class="word">Hi</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-2 anime-text-1">
          <span class="word">There</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-3 anime-text-2">
          <span class="word">Mr. John</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

There are some javascript functions which allows the images from `image-area` class to be dropped in the `map` class

```
function drag(evt) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("image", evt.target.id);
}

function drop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("image");
  var image = document.getElementById(data);
  evt.target.appendChild(image);
}

function allowDrop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

In this current implementation `banner-area` and `banner-area-2` both divs are visible. I want to hide this `banner-area-2` div initially and show it when all the images from `image-area` is dragged to the `map` class and also hide `banner-area` using javascript.

Here is the CSS file:

```
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.banner-area {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("../img/default.png");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.banner-area__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.banner-area__green {
  color: green;
}

.banner-area__red {
  color: red;
}

.map {
  width: 115px;
  height: 156px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.map1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.map2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 25px;
}

.map3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
}

.map4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 20px;
}

.image-area {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.image-area div {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.banner-area-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("../img/final.png");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-area {
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(355deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.text-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/green2.png");
}

.text-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/red.png");
}

.text-3 {
  background-image: url("../img/green1.png");
}

.anime-text,
.anime-text-1,
.anime-text-2,
.word {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should hide `banner-area-2` on loading your application then you need to make sure to show it only when `image-area` has no images left.

It's pretty simple code which checks every time your drop an image to `map` area and when there are no more images left then it shows the `banner-area-2`.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('banner-area-2')[0].style.display = 'none';
let imagespacechildren = document.getElementsByClassName('image-area')[0].children

function drag(evt) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("image", evt.target.id);
}


function drop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("image");
  var image = document.getElementById(data);
  evt.target.appendChild(image);
  let numberofImageLeft = countImages();
  if (numberofImageLeft === 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('banner-area-2')[0].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function countImages() {
  let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < imagespacechildren.length; i++) {
    count +=
      imagespacechildren[i].childElementCount;
  }
  return count;
}

function allowDrop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.banner-area {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("../img/default.png");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.banner-area__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.banner-area__green {
  color: green;
}

.banner-area__red {
  color: red;
}

.map {
  width: 115px;
  height: 156px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.map1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.map2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 25px;
}

.map3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
}

.map4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 20px;
}

.image-area {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.image-area div {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.banner-area-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("../img/final.png");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-area {
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(355deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.text-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/green2.png");
}

.text-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/red.png");
}

.text-3 {
  background-image: url("../img/green1.png");
}

.anime-text,
.anime-text-1,
.anime-text-2,
.word {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-area">
  <div class="banner-area__text">
    <span class="banner-area__green">Place</span>
    <span class="banner-area__red">Images</span>
  </div>
  <div class="map">
    <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="map1"></div>
    <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="map2"></div>
    <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="map3"></div>
    <div id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="map4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-area">
    <div id="container1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="./img/hatirjheel.png" alt="hatirjheel" class="small-image" id="image1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
    </div>
    <div id="container2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="./img/jamuna.png" alt="hatirjheel" class="small-image" id="image2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
    </div>
    <div id="container3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="./img/padma.png" alt="hatirjheel" class="small-image" id="image3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
    </div>
    <div id="container4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="./img/ruppur.png" alt="hatirjheel" class="small-image" id="image4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="banner-area-2" id="div1">
  <div class="text-area">
    <div class="text-1 anime-text">
      <span class="word">Hi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-2 anime-text-1">
      <span class="word">There</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-3 anime-text-2">
      <span class="word">Mr. John</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```